# Splitting strings and checking each separately

Tags: c#, string, split

I'm a beginner at C# trying to learn myself and i'm doing an exercise which requires the following.

Make a label, textbox and button, the textbox contains a number in format XXX-XXX-XXX where each X is a digit from 0-9. So, I have to check if the given number is valid (9 digits) and if the first three digits of the number are (070, 071, 072, 075, 076, 077, 078).

So basically, each number has to start with those 3 numbers and then check the rest 6 digits if they are 6 (not more) and if they're digits from 0-9.

Here's my code so far:

```
private void btnProveri_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = txtTelefon.Text;
    string[] nums = s.Split('-');
    foreach (string num in nums)
    {
        if (num.Length > 3)
        {
            lblRezultat.Text = "Invalid number.";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do it further? Check if first three digits are specific ones and check if the rest splits are 3 digits each (a check if they're digits from 0-9 (not chars) would be good also).

Comment: Sounds like a job for a regular expression.

Comment: Do you have to use `Split`?  What about a regex?  Something like `^[070|071|072|075|076|077|078](\-\d{3}){2}$` (off the top of my head..probably a bit off but the idea is to see if the first 3 digits match what you're looking for followed by 2 groups of `-` and 3 digits.

Comment: Yes, I have to use Split() unfortunately.. (the task specifies that) I'd like to solve with Split() first then improve my C# by solving it with Regex as well.

Comment: Consider using Masked Textbox: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the following solution you can use [`IEnumerable.Contains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check the first the digits against your criteria.  This checks each member against your value.

Then after making sure each value is three digits, I attempt to convert it to an integer to ensure it is in the proper format with [`Int32.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string s = txtTelefon.Text;
string[] nums = s.Split('-');
int counter = 0;
IEnumerable<string> first = new List<string> { "070", "071", "072", "075", "076", "077", "078" };
foreach (string num in nums)
{
    if (num.Length != 3)
    {
        lblRezultat.Text = "Invalid number.";
        break;
    }
    else if (counter==0)
    {
        if (!first.Contains(num))
        {
            // first 3 digits don't match pattern
            break;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        int try = 0;
        if (!int.TryParse(num, try))
        {
             // not a 3 digit number
             break;
        }
    }

    counter++
}
if (counter != 3)
{
    // wrong number of splits (111-222-333-444)
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me what IEnumerable<string> first is? (Sorry if it's obivous question, I'm very new to C#)

Comment: good answer, talks to what the OP was specifically asking (no Regex, LINQ, etc.)

Comment: True, but I needed it with Split().. whatever.. I'll see what I can do. Maybe some hint from OP?

Comment: @user2699298.  You are still using your split.  This is just to replace your `foreach` loop.

Comment: @Harrison Now I understand.. what confused me in all answers is that everyone ignored my part of code and simply added their code. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: @Harrison Just one thing that I can't understand. Why do we use the counter?

Comment: @user2699298.  The counter is so that you can separate the first num from the other two, as this has different rules then the following two num strings.

Answer (score 5):

This LINQ approach should work, no need to parse it to `int` or to use regex:

```
string[] nums = "076-123-456".Split('-');
var startNums = new[]{"070","071","072","075","076","077","078"};
bool valid = nums.Length == 3 && 
             startNums.Contains(nums[0]) &&
             nums.Skip(1).All(n => n.Length==3 && n.All(Char.IsDigit));
```

Comment: Figures there'd be a neat and tidy LINQ approach :)  Though is the second line a typo: `if (valid) valid = valid = startNums.Contains(nums[0]);`?  Looks like an extra `valid =` in there.

Comment: Nice simple solution. Linq makes everything so much more compact  +1

Answer (score 2):

Give the example in your question a single regular expression would solve the question:

```
var pattern = @"^07[0125678]-\d{3}-\d{3}$"
```

The above would match any string starting 07X with X is in the square brackets, followed by hyphen and then three digits, repeated twice.

```
if( !Regex.IsMatch(txtTelefon.Text, pattern) )
{
    lblRezultat.Text = "Invalid number.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var s = "XXX-XXX-XXX";
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^[070|071|072|075|076|077|078]-\d{3}-\d{3}$")))
    {
        //wrong format
    }
```

Comment: This will match 111-322-211, which is not what OP is looking for.

Comment: The first 3 digits have to match 070, 071, 072, 075, 076, 077, 078 (and some others I'll add myself)

Comment: I have fixed my answer - sorry